# Munchkin: card attributes in the event of helping another player

Tags: munchkin

Assume that a player turns up the *Ogre Achiever* upon kicking down the door, and cannot kill it alone.

Given that the card's description (excluding 'Bad Stuff') is:

> +5 against **anyone** who doesn't have a Class *and* a Faction.

(**bold** emphasis mine)

If the original player who looted the room *and* the person helping **both** do not have a class **and** a faction, would the resulting monster have +10 against the team of 2 players?

If so or if not, a specification from the rulebook would be appreciated! I have had no luck in finding anything in the original game's rulebook nor the expansion (*Pathfinder*).

Comment: I don't know where the rule is stated explicitly, so I won't post it as an answer. But I believe such modifiers can only be activated once. As the drawing player already triggered that modifier, the helping player cannot trigger it again.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find a specific rule in either the rule book or FAQ but the [following post](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?s=d936962bcc613932174362270e4e1c6e&p=963268&postcount=9) from the Steve Jackson Games forum. According to them, the card must explicitly state that the effect stacks. So in your case, the maximum would be +5 to the monsters level.

> In my examples, x will always be 5, y will always be 2. A will be
>   Dwarf and B will be Elf. The Dwarf/Anything or Elf/Anything means
>   Anything except human. The reason behind this is because of the
>   Half-breed card that allows you to ignore disadvantages of the single
>   race you have, as long as you have Half-breed too.
>
> **1: +x against A & B = +x if A and/or B.**
>
> Monster Card says: +5 against Dwarf & Elf
>
> It means that the monster gets a +5 if you're a Dwarf, Dwarf/Anything,
>   Dwarf/Elf, Elf/Anything, Elf.
>
> **2: +x against A & B and it stacks = +x if only A or only B, +2x if A & B.**
>
> Monster Card says: +5 against Dwarf & Elf, and card specifies that it
>   stacks.
>
> It means that the monster gets a +5 if you're a Dwarf OR an Elf. If
>   you're a Dwarf AND an Elf, the monster get +10 in this case.
>   Dwarf/Anything minus Elf and Elf/Anything minus Dwarf only get +5.
>
> Important note; a Monster getting a bonus against multiple races
>   usually only get the bonus once. Same for multiple classes, or other
>   such things, since they're the same source; Bonus vs Race, or vs
>   Class, or vs whatever. HOWEVER, a combination of those, a Bonus vs
>   Race AND a Bonus vs Class will always stack, since it's a different
>   source. Only the monster cards that SPECIFY that their bonus stack for
>   2 different Races, Classes or Whatever, will have it stack. An example
>   of such cards would be #3.
>
> **3 +x against A, +y against B = +x if only A, +y if only B, +(x+y) if A & B.**
>
> Monster Card says: +5 against Dwarf, +2 against Elf. +7 if both.
>
> This one is fairly simple. It means that if you're a Dwarf or
>   Dwarf/Anything, minus Elf, the monster gets a bonus of +5. If you're
>   an Elf or Elf/Anything, minus Dwarf, the monster gets a bonus of +2.
>   If you're Dwarf/Elf, the +5 and +2 stack, and create a +7 bonus for
>   the monster, hence the "if both".
>
> Negatives can appear instead of those positive Bonuses. Some might
>   even have both, in which case one would be added and the other would
>   be substracted. In my examples, it would be something like +5 against
>   Dwarf, -2 Against Elf. In this case, it doesn't have to specify "if
>   both" because, while they're from the same source (Race), one's a
>   Disadvantage (the +5 against Dwarf) and the other's an Advantage (the
>   -2 against Elf).

The rules (in bold) themselves supposedly come from Steve Jackson (although I can't confirm that), the further explanations are from a forum member.

Comment: I'll vote up for you explanations of other scenarios that are specific for particular cases where the language is clear - but in this particular situation I'm questioning the word *anyone*, which could apply to **just** the original door-kicker or the **entire team** (individually), which affects the result of combat.